# How these two queries works with and or clauses?

Tags: postgresql

`select * from users where id=1 or 1=1;` . It returns all the rows from table users;

`select * from users where id=1 and 1=1;` It returns all the rows specific to id=1;

Comment: Is this supposed to be a question?

Comment: Wanted to understand how both the queries works.

Comment: First says "OR 1=1", which is always TRUE, thus returns all records. Second says id=1 AND TRUE, thus returns records where id=1 only. You could rewrite the first one as "select * from users" and second as "select * from users where id=1".

Answer (score 0):

The expression `x or y` is true if either `x` or is `y` is true.  Thus, in the first sql you give the `where` clause evaluated as true for any row (as `1` is clearly always equal to `1`).

In contrast `x and y` is true only when *both* `x` and `y` are true.  Thus, in the second sql you give the `where` clause evaluated as true only for those rows where `id` is `1`.